# Player instance fetched by new method doesn't work for iOS safari

Tags: jquery, html, ios, safari, mediaelement.js

Hi I have tried a couple of ways (officially or unofficially) to get an instance of the player. Only one way works for PC browsers, but it does not work for iOS safari. (iPad mini in my case.)

In , I implemented this:

```
<video id="player1" src="/videos/docTest.mp4" width="480" height="320" ></video>
```

And in , I initialized the video in this way:

```
        $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
            // do something
            features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'volume', 'fullscreen'],
            iPadUseNativeControls: false,
            iPhoneUseNativeControls: false,
            AndroidUseNativeControls: false,

        });
```

as what is shown on mediaelementplayer website. And this is the only way I found the player works.

Later, I need to do some customized styling job, which is to mark jump points on progress bar. I succeeded in doing this by calling

`var player1 = MediaElementPlayer('#player1');`

. However, this line (and only this line) would cause the player totally down on iOS safari. On my ipad, the player won't be able to play the video.

The additional feature I am working on requires me to get the instance of the player. Is there any working way other than the one that I used to get the player instance? Thanks!

Personally, I think it could be a big problem for developers if they were unable to get an instance of the player.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var player = $('#player1').mediaelementplayer();
```

Or if that doesn't work this also works for me:

```
var player = $('#player1')[0].player;
```

You can then add event listeners etc. to the player:

```
player.media.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
}, false);
```